# opencart email not working

Tags: php, email, ssl, opencart

I'm using OPENCART and mail has suddenly stopped working all over the site

Has goddadys server settings changed again for email? no matter what settings I use SSL/Mail no emails coming through
not working on anything, registration, lost password, with admin

tried mail

```
mail.mysite.com
------------------
smtp
ssl://mysite.com
username
password
post 465
```

etc
nothing is working

> Email to required is back on line 61 mail.php
>
> EHLO error is back if you try SSL
>   2016-10-05 6:54:12 - PHP Notice:  Error: EHLO not accepted from server! in /public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 201
>
> without SSL
>   2016-10-04 16:43:31 - PHP Notice:  Error: E-Mail to required! in /public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 60

No code has changed on the site... help please

Answer (score 0):

fixed it.... catalog/model/account/customer.php

```
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'),ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($this->language->get('text_new_customer'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

and I may be wrong but think this should be

```
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('email'));
```